# Is there an algorithm for finding log(n) order statistics in linear time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, deterministic

Can I build an algorithm FindStats(A,k)

which receives an input array A of size n and an integer k such that 2^k <= n (which means k is in the worst case log(n)) and outputs A's 1,2,4,8,...,2^k order statistics.
all that in linear time!

What have I tried so far:

I know there is an algorithm QuickSelect(A,k) (deterministic algorithm) which returns the k'th order statistic in a linear time, but in my case the trivial solution which is to go over all the 1,2,4,8...,2^k order statistics and return the will result in O(nlogn).

Can I improve it? Is it even possible to achive it?

Comment: Quickselect has *average* linear performance. It's worst case remains quadratic due to poor pivot selection.

Comment: @AndyG normally true, but good to be aware that a better worst case time-complexity quickselect is possible (with quite complex) median-of-medians.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jim Mischel's answer was applying similar logic. I'm not sure why that answer was deleted.

If we admit that there is any selection algorithm that can guarantee a single `k`th order statistic in `O(n)` time, then finding the `1st, 2nd, 4th, 8th..., 2^kth` is also achievable in `O(n)` time. This is due to simple algebra:

```
let a = 2^k
then the sequence,
  a + 1/2*a + 1/4*a + 1/8*a + 1/16*a ...
converges and can never exceed 2*a
```

This means if after (or during) each selection, we partition the list into a section half its size and make that the input for the next selection, the total input we pass to the selection algorithm will never exceed `O(n)`. Our time calculation would look like:

```
find 2^kth:       n
find 1/2 * 2^kth: 2^k
find 1/4 * 2^kth: 2^(k-1)
find 1/8 * 2^kth: 2^(k-2)
...

The sum on the right cannot exceed
n + 2^(k + 1)
=> O(n + 2^(log2(n) + 1))
=> O(n)

(If it takes an extra traversal to
 partition the list after each selection,
 the summation could add another n,
 not affecting the general complexity.)
```

Another idea that interested me is whether we could somehow use a heapifying method to guarantee all cousins are smaller than the cousins on the next level. Doing this efficiantly enough could then also guarantee an O(n) solution using a breadth first search to traverse each level of this special heap.